# How can I format MySQL date response to be MM-DD-YYYY?

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, format

Does anyone know how to format this MySQL response to have JUST the date in the format of MM-DD-YYYY? For example, I want the below response to be formatted in 12-02-2020

```
date: '2020-12-02T08:00:00.000Z'
```

I tried doing the lines below but didn't seem to work

```
let formattedDate = new Date(Date.parse(entry.date.replace(/-/g, '/')));
```

Comment: The duplicate question is almost exactly what you need. Just replace `[year, month, day]` with `[month, day, year]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_format()` in your SQL query:

```
date_format(mydate, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: do you know if there is a way to do it without using SQL queries?